Can I setup new electrical combo panel on new retrofit wood?
I am working on changing electrical panel.
Our current panel is a flush panel, the self-supported mast penetrates up the 1ft wood beam, so we intend to use the same penetration hole, instead of drilling a new one.
We need to stick a wood to a stud, so the panel can be in the right horizontal location.
Something like this [old / new]:


We can't really put the blue stud top-to-bottom, because there is a anchoring bolt there. Do you know if this setup reasonable, and if it may violate any code? Any code saying that the panel needs to be directly on top-to-bottom stud?
Thanks in advance!

I do not know code, but panels are not that heavy and a spacer/filler stud/wood should work.  Unknown if anchor bolts need to be accessible or if a hole/notch drilled into bottom of a stud is allowed now.

This panel is a flush panel, we plan to install siemens mc2442b1200esv
Do you mean the just adding one block of wood should already be enough?
Like larger block of the blue? Not even need to add new top-to-bottom stud? Sorry, I know my terminology is probably all wrong

The structural loads are already being carried. If all you need is a filler strip, a filler strip the length of the panel and thick enough to reach the corner stud is all you need, with a few screws or nails to hold it in place.
If you're feeling paranoid (no reason to) you could use 4 inch screws to secure that side of the electrical panel so they go through your (as drawn, anyway) two pieces of 1.5" blocking material and into the corner stud. But that's really not called for or needed. Nothing whatsoever requires an additional full length stud here, much less two. Attaching one piece of blocking to the stud, the next to that one, and panel to the next is entirely adequate to hold the panel up. If you do choose overly long screws, be sure to pilot drill so they don't get stuck or break partway into the hole.

I mean, if you're really worried, you could just sister a short 2x4 to the stud on the right, just below the panel, or stick 2x4s in between (what I assume are) the conduit runs that come out the bottom of the panel.
